# Find the number of steps transforming a/b into c/d so that 0<a<b<100000 and 0<c<d<100000, or none if there is no ways

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, equation, fractions

> *Original problem.* Given two valid fractions `a/b` and `c/d`. Each transformation is adding `1` to `a` and `b`, then optimizing `a/b`. Find the number of steps transforming `a/b` into `c/d` so that `0<a<b<100000` and  `0<c<d<100000`, or none if there is no ways.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int x, int y) {
    while(y) {
        int r=x%y;
        x=y;
        y=r;
    }
    return x;
}
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
    int i=0;
    while (b<d) {
        if (a*d<b*c) {
            a++;
            b++;
            a/=gcd(a, b);
            b/=gcd(a, b);
            i++;
        }
        else if (a*d==b*c) {
            cout<<i;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout<<0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Something wrong, i.e., for input

```
1
6
2
3
```

The answer is `5`, but not an output here.. I need to the help, thanks for all your nice comments !

Comment: What does _"something wrong"_ mean?

Comment: @hd_30102 Please do not change the question to a different one, especially after it was answered (and accepted, for that matter). You can always ask a new question, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is `while (b<d)`. In your example `6<3` is wrong so the while loop is completely skipped.

The next problem is

```
a/=gcd(a, b);
b/=gcd(a, b);
```

You are changing `a` and calculating two different gcd for `a` and `b`.

You can fix it with

```
const auto g = gcd(a, b);
a/=g;
b/=g;
```

Comment: What does `b->100000` mean?

Comment: How could that be possible? Do you have an example?

Comment: @hd_30102 I commented your question. It's not possible.